# Hooking Generic Repository With IOC container

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unity-container, autofac

I am trying to create a generic repository pattern where i can swtich ORM technogies , But i stumbled upon this problem when trying to hook with IOC container

```
 public interface IRepository<T>  
 {
      //members
 }
```

For NHbernate this works fine

```
public class FNHRepository<T>: IRepository<T> 
{ //members }
```

But for Entity i am forced to add where clause

```
public class EFRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class 
{
```

if i am omiting the "where clause" i am not able to do

```
dbset = DataContext.Set<T>() ;
```

saying only reference type can be used as T

The problem comes when i am trying to hook IRepository with an IOC , like this

```
.RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(EFRepository<>));
```

I am not able to hook the interface if the implemeting class is having  **where T : class**  , I am getting the following execption

xception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, System.Web.Mvc.IControllerFactory, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

Any help appriciated , i tried this with Unity and Autofac and getting the same error

Comment: try adding the same restriction to your interface.

Comment: i had originaly started like that but when i add 'where T : class', ioc hooking throwing error

Comment: InvalidOperationException - The current type, System.Web.Mvc.IControllerFactory, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping

Comment: Show the inner exception which shows the actual details

Comment: [System.InvalidOperationException] = {"The current type, System.Web.Mvc.IControllerFactory, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?"}

Comment: Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "System.Web.Mvc.IControllerFactory", name = "(none)".
Exception occurred while: while resolving.
Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, System.Web.Mvc.IControllerFactory, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?
-----------------------------------------------
At the time of the exception, the container was:

  Resolving System.Web.Mvc.IControllerFactory,(none)

Comment: We'd really like to get you an answer here, but it feels like you're asking at least two disconnected questions.  Is the type constraint causing the error somehow?  I've done something similar to this (though not with the same intent) successfully.  Can you show us a little bit more of your container registration code?  Have you registered IControllerFactory and/or correctly followed the setup instructions for MVC integration?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Unity, but you should be able to register a generic class with constraints just fine.

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(EFRepo...))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

The problem though is this: without the same constraint on the interface, this is bound to fail:

```
container.Resolve<IRepo<int>>();
```

Comment: i added builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes().AsImplementedInterfaces(); still getting the error,  i thought the error gone but still there